# How to check the compatible screens for an Android application?

Tags: android

I want my Android app not to be visible in the Play Store to people using a tablet.

I've made the changes to the AndroidManifest that were described in the documentation, and I'm sure it'll work, but I cannot update the apk unless I'm a 100% sure that it does.

The thing is, there is apparently no other way to check than to update the current production version...

Is there anyway I could make sure my `compatible-screen` setting works well, without any disturbance for the application users ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at the [compatible screens documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)?

They have this little excerpt here that may be helpful:

> The Android system does not read the  manifest element (neither at install-time nor at runtime). This element is informational only and may be used by external services (such as Google Play) to better understand the application's compatibility with specific screen configurations and enable filtering for users. **Any screen configuration that is not declared in this element is a screen with which the application is not compatible. Thus, external services (such as Google Play) should not provide the application to devices with such screens.**

Does that help?